# Python subprocesss: call an instance method

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using Python 2.7. I want to create an instance of an object, and call a method within it in a separate process. Something like this:

```
import subprocesss
class A
   def doAwork(self, text):
      print text

class B
   def doBWork
      aInst = A()
      subprocess(A.dowork("called from doBwork"))
```

Can this be done, or, do I need to turn around and call python as a subprocesss?

**Edit:**
I can not use threads for this. The method called in aInst in reality loads a non-thread safe dll.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead of `subprocess`

Simple example copied from documentation link above:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

With your example it would look like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class A:
   def doAwork(self, text):
      print text

class B:
   def doBweork(self):
      aInst = A()
      p = Process(target=aInst.doAwork("called from doBWork")
      p.start()
      p.join()
```

Comment: I probably could have stated my original problem with more detail. But, in reality, I am calling into this class from a C++ via the python.h header and PyImport_ImportModule(), etc. This is really strange. But, when I call p.start() as above, another instance of my calling exe is created.

Comment: Isn't that correct? I thought you wanted the code to execute in another (sub)process.

Comment: I have a C++ exe creating the python instance. The python instance needs to turn around and create a new process to execute the python code. Instead, a new C++ exe is launched so that I have 2 of them instead of a new process running aInst.doWork()

Comment: Oh that's strange. I see now the documentation states this: `Functionality within this package requires that the __main__ module be importable by the children`. Probably the __main__ module is in this case your C++ program, and so it gets started. But I have not used python from C++ yet, so I can't answer this now. (If I find something I will update my answer)

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` is used to spawn a process (EXE on windows) and not a function. In this case, you may use threads:

```
import thread

class A:
   def doAwork(self, text):
      print text

class B:
   def doBwork(self):
      aInst = A()
      thread.start_new_thread(aInst.doAwork, ("called from doBwork",))

B().doBwork()
```

Comment: I can't do in thread. I specifically need separate processes because the actual code loads a dll that is not thread safe. I will update the question to reflect this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

multiprocessing  http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
The Process class will give you all you need